# php arrays and loops

Tags: php

I have an array which runs in a for loop

for example

```
Array
(
    [0] => xyz
    [1] => abc
)

Array
(
    [0] => xyz
    [1] => abc
)

Array
(
    [0] => xyz.com
    [1] => xyz.co.uk
    [2] => xyz-west.co.uk
    [3] => xyz.com
    [4] => xyz.co.uk
    [5] => xyz.com
    [6] => xyz.com
)

Array
(
    [0] => xyz.com
    [1] => xyz.ca
    [2] => xyz.com
    [3] => xyz.com
    [4] => xyz.com
    [5] => xyz.com
    [6] => xyz.com
    [7] => xyz.com
    [8] => xyz
)
```

Now i want to know if there is a way to get the top five arrays with maximum array count (i.e with maximum elements in them)

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you are looking for is

```
$myElements=count($myArray);
```

which you can pop into a loop to see which one has the most elements.

If you have arrays with more than one dimension you can still get a count of ALL the elements in it like this:

```
$myElements=count($myArray, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
```

which will count all the elements, not just the first level.

Answer (score 0):

first use [count function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to count array elements for all array,
then save all counts in one array, and sort it with [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), and then you will get top 5. .